# convergence of power serial $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{1000}}{\sqrt{n!}}x^n$

Tags: analysis

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{1000}}{\sqrt{n!}}x^n$$
I am trying to find such $x$ that this serial is covergent.
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|= \frac{(n+1)^{1000}}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{n^{1000}}=\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{1000}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
$$
Now, I try to find radius:
$$R=\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{1000}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}=\left[\frac10\right]=\infty$$

Now I am confused, because I don't know how to finish this taks. Can you help me ?

Comment: Despite the appearance, the coefficients of the power series approach zero faster than $\frac{1}{c^n}$ for any $c>1$, hence the given function is an entire function and the series is convergent for *any* $x$.

Comment: If the OP is doing a ratio test, I am missing a limit here

Answer (score 1):

This means that the radius of convergence of the given power series is *infinite*, we have
$$
\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{1000}}{\sqrt{n!}}x^n\right|<\infty
$$ for *any* complex value of $x$.

Comment: You want the absolute values inside the sum.

Comment: Not really, the above inequality is true *as it stands*, since it is *dominated* by the series of absolute values.